# Require assistance with creating an auto log-in program for gmail using c++

Tags: html, c++, visual-studio-2013

As stated above I require assistance with an auto log-in program. I want the program to open the log-in page, find the email and password elements in the form, then insert the relative info into their related text box, finally it would activate the log-in button and the account would be signed in. Mind you that this is to be programmed in c++

I've looked online and have only found examples in C#, Auto-it, visual basic, or batch. Sadly these examples aren't the answer I'm looking. I am hoping I can receive some help and be guided in the right direction to accomplish this.

I programmed this in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 and all I have been able to do is have it open up to to the log-in screen

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shellapi.h>
#include <stdio.h> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

    system("pause");
}
```

Am I to call  certain classes, functions, or do I need certain library extensions. Whats do I do next.

p.s. I've only started c++ 3 months ago doing small projects on the side but this ones just really got me stumped.

Comment: The (reasonable) approach to this general problem from C++ is to write a POP3 (or IMAP4) client. If you really want to control a browser, you probably want to create a project that embeds an IWebBrowser2, which gives your program a great deal more control over how the browser does its thing (but also requires a great deal more work on your part).

Comment: This sounds like a what I was looking for. I'll give this a try and let you know how this turns out.